# C# asp.net MySQL either Null or Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, json.net

So, when I try to call a string with asp.net such as `e7af78997ef220a557c97a1a4c11e0c2` the return always comes back null. I know for a fact it isn't null (all ID's are in that format or in an IP format). and it works when I input an int column.

So my problem is that The return is always null, and Visual Studio says

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

I know it has to do with `MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from a3bans.bans where GUID = '" + ban.GuidOrIP + "' ; ", conDataBase);` and I'm almost positive it has to do with

```
'" + ban.GuidOrIP + "' ; ", conDataBase);`
```

I think I've tried a million ways and and either have gotten syntax errors or `Null`

I think the issue has to do with the Database input rather than output. Input as in "select" I put in the ID just using a regular query and it populated the information, however. When trying to use my tban (the { getter; Setter;} it just returns Null...

Every thing that I have researched has referenced to a button with .Text and nothing seems to help with a getter and setter..

I am sure it's something very simple I am over looking. I'm very new to C# and what may take you 2 minutes may take me 6 hours... like this...

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("A3Bans/searchBan")]
        public string oSearchBan(tBan ban)
        {
            {
                tBan bans = new tBan();
                string dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=admin;password=00000";
                MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
                MySqlDataReader dbReader;
                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from a3bans.bans where GUID = '" + ban.GuidOrIP + "' ; ", conDataBase); // Returning a null value?!

                conDataBase.Open();
                dbReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    tBan searchBan = new tBan();
                    searchBan.GuidOrIP = dbReader.GetString("GUID");
                    searchBan.BanType = dbReader.GetString("BanType");
                    searchBan.BanReason = dbReader.GetString("Reason");
                    searchBan.Proof = dbReader.GetString("Proof");
                    bans = searchBan;
                }
                dbReader.Close();
                return bans.Proof;


            }
        }
```

If I replace the query string with string `selectQuery = "Select * FROM a3bans.bans WHERE BanID=" + int.Parse(schBanID.Text);` It will return the proper values from the client side. and If i were to translate it to the API it alreturns the correct values. But it is an int and not a string.

***Update:***
Tried, Still not working.
Man I still can't wrap my head around it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("A3Bans/searchBan")]
    public string oSearchBan(tBan ban)
    {
        {
            tBan bans = new tBan();
            string dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=admin;password=00000";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
            MySqlDataReader dbReader;

            conDataBase.Open();

            // Returns a null value from bans.Proof
            // If placing a /w real GUID without null fields, rather than "ban.GuidOrIP" , the return populates properly. 

            MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM a3bans.bans WHERE (GUID) LIKE(@GUID)", conDataBase);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GUID", bans.GuidOrIP);
            selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dbReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

This still returns `null`

Comment: You can get this error if `BanType`, `BanReason` or `Proof` in the class `tBan` is something other than a string. If for example `BanType` is an `int`, you need to cast or convert the database output.

Comment: I am converting it to Json from the client side and using Json in a web App called Post man to check it. that portion seems to work.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with the Database input rather than output. Input as in "select" I put in the ID just using a regular query and it populated the information, however. When trying to use my tban (the { getter; Setter;} it just returns Null...